# Why can't I find a USB-C powerbank for my laptop?

Tags: power-bank

I've been digging around for a few weeks now and I've been unable to find a powerbank to support my Thinkpad so I can be "off grid" longer than a couple hours.

The specs I'm looking for seem pretty standard:

- Lots of juice (~50,000mAh)
- USB-C out at a level capable of supporting my Thinkpad, which requires (I think) 65W.
- Passthrough charging.
- Must be permitted on a plane as a carry-on.
- USB-C in for fast charging would be nice.

What I've found so far are a lot of things that appear to be *trying* to look like the above, but fall short in critical areas:

- USB-C used for charging the powerbank only, with standard USB-A ports for outgoing.
- USB-C out is available, but only at a power level capable of charging phones.
- Support for charging a laptop, but only by way of a standard AC outlet on the powerbank, so I have to cart around my adapter (which presumably wastes energy to do the conversion).

I feel like this should be an easy, solvable problem, that I should be able to run a 2-sided USB-C cable from the powerbank to my laptop, so maybe I'm just not looking in the right place?  Am I missing something that makes this sort of request fundamentally impossible or prohibitively expensive?  I'm just wanting to know if I'm looking for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: AFAIK, that combination is not possible, because you can only carry a battery on a plane that is less than 100Wh (+- 27000 mAh)

Comment: And if a phone powerbank supports 65W charging usb-c, your laptop should also support it

Comment: It may just be easier to have two large batteries and a docking hub. I know it may not be the most elegant, but it's better than having a laptop die on you.